# Gantt chart creation is causing program error

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA program that I created a long time ago. In its original document it work perfectly and outputs something that looks like the following:

[image: main]

However, when I copy the input sheet and VBA code to a new document that set up exactly the same it gives me a

> Runtime error 13: type mismatch error

on the line that says `EndTime = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR5)` about halfway down the code.

```
Public RESOL As Single
Public StepRow As Integer       'this is the start ROW for the STEP numbers
Public StepColumn As Integer    'this is the COLUMN for the STEP numbers
Public VAR3 As Integer          'this is the COLUMN for ABSOLUTE START
Public VAR4 As Integer          'this is the COLUMN for LINK
Public VAR5 As Integer          'this is the COLUMN for DURATION
Public VAR6 As Integer          'this is the COLUMN for the first time period
Public VAR7 As Integer  '       this is the ROW for the labels
Public RowPos As Single
Public TotalTime As Single
Public x1 As Single
Public RowIndex As Integer
Public LastColumn As Integer
Public StartTime As Single
Public EndTime As Single
Public WindowSize As Single

Sub Chart()

    StepRow = 5         ' starting row for step numbers
    StepColumn = 2      ' this is the COLUMN for the STEP numbers
    VAR3 = 4            ' this is the COLUMN for ABSOLUTE START
    VAR4 = 5            ' this is the COLUMN for LINK
    VAR5 = 6            ' this is the COLUMN for DURATION
    VAR6 = 11            ' this is the COLUMN for the first time period
    VAR7 = 3            ' this is the ROW for the labels.

    RESOL = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, VAR3)

    'when the resolution to .01 if less than .01
    If RESOL < 0.01 Then
        MsgBox ("Grid resolution must be at least .01")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    LastColumn = VAR6
    TotalTime = 0
    RowIndex = StepRow
    CheckNum = 1

    Do
        x = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, StepColumn)

        ' bomb if no step number present
        If IsNumeric(x) = False Then
            MsgBox ("Couldn't find a step number at position " & CheckNum)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If x < 1 Then
            LastNum = CheckNum - 1
            Exit Do
        End If


        If x <> CheckNum Then
            MsgBox ("Step number does not match position" & CheckNum)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
        CheckNum = CheckNum + 1

    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Lines.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(VAR7, VAR6), Cells(VAR7, 256)).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WindowSize = ActiveWindow.Zoom
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    RowIndex = StepRow
    CheckNum = 1

    Do
        LinkPos = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR4)

        If Val(LinkPos) > LastNum Then
            MsgBox ("Illegal LINK number for step " + CheckNum)
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = WindowSize
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Val(LinkPos) < 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR4).Formula = Empty
        End If

        If Val(LinkPos) > 0 And Val(LinkPos) <= LastNum Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR3).Formula = "NA"
        End If

        If CheckNum = LastNum Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        CheckNum = CheckNum + 1
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1

    Loop

    CompletedSteps = 0
    RowIndex = StepRow
    CheckNum = 1

    Do
        AbsPos = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR3)

        If AbsPos <> "NA" And IsNumeric(AbsPos) = True Then
            StartTime = Val(AbsPos)
            EndTime = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR5)
            EndTime = EndTime + StartTime
            Run ("DrawLine")
            CompletedSteps = CompletedSteps + 1
        End If

        If CheckNum = LastNum Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        CheckNum = CheckNum + 1
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
    Loop

    NoOfTries = 1

    Do

        If CompletedSteps = LastNum Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        RowIndex = StepRow
        CheckNum = 1

        Do
            LinkTo = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR4)

            If Val(LinkTo) >= 1 And Val(LinkTo) <= LastNum Then

                AbsPos = ActiveSheet.Cells(StepRow - 1 + LinkTo, VAR3)

                If AbsPos <> "NA" And IsNumeric(AbsPos) = True Then
                    DurPos = ActiveSheet.Cells(StepRow - 1 + LinkTo, VAR5)
                    AbsPos = AbsPos + DurPos
                    StartTime = Val(AbsPos)
                    EndTime = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR5)
                    EndTime = EndTime + StartTime
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR3).Formula = StartTime
                    Run ("DrawLine")
                    Top1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(StepRow - 1 + LinkTo, VAR6).Top
                    Top2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(StepRow + LinkTo, VAR6).Top
                    RowPos2 = Top1 + ((Top2 - Top1) / 2)

                    Set mySheet = ActiveSheet
                    With mySheet.Shapes.AddLine(x1, RowPos, x1, RowPos2).Line
                        .DashStyle = msoLineDash
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End With

                    CompletedSteps = CompletedSteps + 1

                End If

            End If

            If CheckNum = LastNum Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            CheckNum = CheckNum + 1
            RowIndex = RowIndex + 1

        Loop

        If NoOfTries = LastNum Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        NoOfTries = NoOfTries + 1
    Loop

    RowIndex = StepRow
    CheckNum = 1

    Do
        LinkPos = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR4)
        If Val(LinkPos) > 0 And Val(LinkPos) <= LastNum Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR3).Formula = Empty
        End If

        If CheckNum = LastNum Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        CheckNum = CheckNum + 1
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
    Loop

    CheckCol = VAR6
    ColVal = RESOL

    Do
        ActiveSheet.Cells(VAR7, CheckCol).Formula = ColVal

        If CheckCol >= LastColumn Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        ColVal = ColVal + RESOL
        CheckCol = CheckCol + 1
    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, VAR3).Formula = TotalTime
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = WindowSize
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub Drawline()
    If EndTime > TotalTime Then
        TotalTime = EndTime
    End If

    Top1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR6).Top
    Top2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex + 1, VAR6).Top
    RowPos = Top1 + ((Top2 - Top1) / 2)
    CheckCol = VAR6
    ColTime = 0

    Do
        x1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, CheckCol).Left

        If ColTime = StartTime Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        If ColTime > StartTime Then
            x2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, CheckCol - 1).Left
            Span = x1 - x2
            Differencial = (ColTime - StartTime) / RESOL
            TimeOffset = Differencial * Span
            x1 = x1 - TimeOffset
            Exit Do
        End If

        ColTime = ColTime + RESOL
        CheckCol = CheckCol + 1

    Loop

    CheckCol = VAR6
    ColTime = 0

    Do
        y1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, CheckCol).Left

        If ColTime = EndTime Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        If ColTime > EndTime Then
            y2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, CheckCol - 1).Left
            Span = y1 - y2
            Differencial = (ColTime - EndTime) / RESOL
            TimeOffset = Differencial * Span
            y1 = y1 - TimeOffset
            Exit Do
        End If

        ColTime = ColTime + RESOL
        CheckCol = CheckCol + 1

    Loop

    If CheckCol > LastColumn Then
        LastColumn = CheckCol
    End If

    Set mySheet = ActiveSheet
    With mySheet.Shapes.AddLine(x1, RowPos - 2, y1, RowPos - 2).Line
        .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 0, 25)
         .Weight = xlHairline
    End With

    With mySheet.Shapes.AddLine(x1, RowPos, y1, RowPos).Line
        .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 0, 25)
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With

    With mySheet.Shapes.AddLine(x1, RowPos + 2, y1, RowPos + 2).Line
        .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 0, 25)
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have the two documents set up exactly the same so I can't figure out why its working on one, but not the other.

**Edit:** below is the state of the document when it errors out. It added all the "NA" to the start time column, but doesn't do that on the original sheet.

[image]

When I comment out the error it works, but prints the following where there are solid bars beneath the gantt chart and the starting bar is solid.

[image]

Comment: Examine the value in that cell - it's most likely text, not a number.

Comment: Side note - use `Long` instead of `Integer`. There is no benefit to using `Integer`, and it in fact can cause issues.

Comment: @BigBen it is a number formatted as general, see my edit in post above

Comment: @BigBen and i went ahead and changed them from Integer to Long but still got the same error

Comment: Where do you declare `x`?  That might be some of the issue.  Also, I'd not use `ActiveSheet`, and use the actual sheet name (or a variable), e.g. `Dim dataWS as Worksheet // Set dataWS = Worksheets("My Data Sheet") // x = dataWS.Cells(RowIndex, VAR5)`.  Also, do you need those variables to really be Public?  That might be an issue. Add `Debug.Print rowIndex, VAR5` right before that line, what is output in the Immediate Window (press `CTRL+G` in the VBEditor).

Comment: `Debug.Print` the value just to make sure that it is what you expect.

Comment: @BigBen when do i put the debug.print

Comment: Comment out the line that errors or put a breakpoint on it, then right before it, `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, VAR5).Value`.

Comment: @BigBen ok so when i comment out the line that was erroring and put in the debug. print line it works except the first bar isnt created and it creates solid bars in all the empty cells below the gantt chart. ill post a screenshot in my question

Comment: What is the output in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)?

Comment: @BigBen when I hit ctrl+G the "go-to" window opens with nothing in it

Comment: Would definitely implement @BruceWayne's suggestion to replace `ActiveSheet` with the actual sheet in question.

Comment: @BigBen i did that as well

Comment: Change `Debug.Print` to `MsgBox` and rerun - what's in the `MsgBox`?

Comment: @BigBen it spits out 1.5 the duration of that first value. but now its stuck in a loop with an empty message box pupping up over and over

Comment: @Vbasic4now - one of your `Cells()` variables is `1.5`?  That's why you're getting an error...

Comment: @BruceWayne where do i define the cell() variable as 1.5? i cant find it

Comment: It hasn't been said here yet so I'll just put it out there. In the Immediate window, type `Print {expression of interest}` to determine the values of long expressions in your code. I use this method all of the time! It's also useful to toggle parameters like `Application.EnableEvents = True` or running subroutines on the fly without having to locate them in the VBE (type `Call MyRoutine` and hit enter)

Comment: @MBB70 we already did suggest `Debug.Print`...

Comment: @BigBen why would the program work perfectly on an identical document but not here?

Comment: A `Type Mismatch` is because the cell in question contains something other than a `Single`. Without your spreadsheet in front of me, I can't tell you what that value is.... it just can't be a `Single`.

Comment: @BigBen can i change that type to look for something else? the cell its tripping up on contains a general formatted number in this case "1.5" but it will error no matter what number i put there

Comment: @BigBen Yes I saw that, thanks...I was suggesting doing things (checking values, executing commands) directly in the Immediate window itself...using it as more than a static debug printer....thought it would be a helpful contribution to this particular conversation. Not trying to step on any toes...just sharing what I think might help.

Comment: I think i figured it out. when i changed the duration cells to "=value" then indicated which cell to pull from it worked.